# Is there a way to dynamically edit content displayed in WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, android-webview

I have a webview with internet website loaded in it and what i want to do is to edit the content dynamically, for instance change the code

```
<button>Search</button>
```

to

```
<button>View</button>
```

What I did so far is I allowed user to load the website then I would take the html, change the content I want and load it into webview.
The content changes fine but the images are not displayed(I guess this happens becuase I do not have the local resources like images etc.).
Is there a way to to dynamically change the content of the online website while preserving all the images,structure etc.?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `evaluateJavascript()` (or, on older devices, `loadUrl("javascript:...")` to execute JavaScript in the context of the currently-loaded Web page, where that JavaScript can alter the DOM, akin to JavaScript that the page might load itself. Whether that will meet your needs, I cannot say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand things correctly, you're loading a page from a website, you change things, and you then send the modified page to the web view.

Then the issue is that the "base URL" is that of your local modified page, not the original website, so any relative URLs (without a domain name) will use this as the base, and of course fail.

One option would be to add:

```
<base href="(original URL of the page goes here)"/>
```

to the `<head>` of your page.

This would solve issues with loading images, CSS, scripts, etc.

However, you would have an issue with anything that is affected by cross-origin protection (Ajax for instance).

Alternatively, you could load the page from its original URL, and use local Javascript to modify the contents of the page.

Comment: It does work quite well but I've encountered a website where this solution(base href) doesn't work, i.e resources doen't get displayed. Thanks though I may use it.

Comment: You must be sure that if there's already a `<base href="xxx"/>` tag you don't overwrite it, of course. And as I said, you'll have issues with cross-origin.